# Bootstrap bulletlists / bulletpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bulletedlist

How can I turn my actual text into bullet-points like in the given example?

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woveq.png)

[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABskh.png)

My Bootstrap code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
        <div class="inside">
          <hgroup>
            <h2>RESPECT FOR THE INDIVIDUAL</h2>
          </hgroup>
          <div class="entry-content">
            <p>• We listen to the other person without interruption and practice effective listening skills.<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&#9642;` which is a **[`html - unicode`](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp)** as below:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="inside">
      <hgroup>
        <h2>RESPECT FOR THE INDIVIDUAL</h2>
      </hgroup>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <p>&#9642; We listen to the other person without interruption and practice effective listening skills.</p>
        <p>&#9642; We do not shy away from challenges</p>
        <p>&#9642; We stay true to our slogan</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Would it be improper to suggest that rather than trying to turn `<p>` elements into a bulleted list - you simply use a bulleted list :_

```
      <div class="entry-content">
       <ul>
          <li>We listen to the other person without interruption and practice effective listening skills.</li>
          <li>We do not shy away from challenges</li>
          <li>We stay true to our slogan</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

seems better than trying to reinvent a circular device that turns or to shoehorn one element into the natural behaviour of another. Just a thought... :))

Comment: Your answer proved to be simple and effective. I just have another doubt: how can I control the bullet colors and text left margin?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is better use ul and li to make a list.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="inside">
            <hgroup>
                <h2>RESPECT FOR THE INDIVIDUAL</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <ul class="entry-content" style="list-style-type: square;">
                <li>We listen to the other person without interruption and practice effective listening skills.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you can use `list-style-type: square;` on ul element to change the style of list item.

I just used inline CSS here, you may add the style into your css file.

For your reference, here is the [HTML-List](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) and [list-style-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp) definition and usage.

Hope this help :)